# gulp-npm-test running Jest tests (all passing), but claiming to fail

Tags: npm, gulp, jestjs, gulp-npm-test

I've installed `gulp-npm-test` following their [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-npm-test#use), that is, in my `gulp` directory I've got a file `test.js` that looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
require('gulp-npm-test')(gulp)

var gulp = require('gulp-npm-test')(gulp, {
  withoutNpmRun: false
})
```

But when I run `gulp test` I get the output like the following:

```
[17:12:41] Using gulpfile ~/my-project/gulpfile.js
[17:12:41] Starting 'test'...

> my-project@0.0.1 test /Users/wogsland/my-project
> jest

 PASS  frontend/tests/components/atoms/InputText.test.js
 .
 .
 (many more Jest test passes, no fails)
 .
 .
 FAIL  gulp/tasks/test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at onResult (node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/TestRunner.js:192:18)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 135 passed, 136 total
Tests:       135 passed, 135 total
Snapshots:   209 passed, 209 total
Time:        92.237s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

What am I missing here? I've go a bunch of tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the matcher that figures out which files are tests, matches everything that includes in the filename `test.js`. The default is `[ '**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)', '**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)' ]`. So either adapt this one, its [`testMatch`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#testmatch-array-string) in your jest settings. Or use [`testPathIgnorePatterns`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#testpathignorepatterns-array-string) to exclude the `/gulp` folder.

Comment: That makes total sense. I'll try it in a bit.

Comment: Modifying my `package.json` to exclude that file was exactly what I needed. Thanks!